# IF statement to start query

Tags: plsql

Can I begin a PL/SQL query with an IF statement? I'm trying to execute the proper SELECT statement based on a parameter.

Comment: What is a `plsql query` ? there is a plsql block which can execute `sql queries`. Do you need to have an `if staement` in plsql or in sql ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/controlstatements.htm Starting point for you. You'll have to add more substance to your question if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can; if the variable/parameter you are trying to compare is already populated with data. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   v_num1 NUMBER := 5;
   v_num2 NUMBER := 3;
   v_temp NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- if v_num1 is greater than v_num2 rearrange their values
   IF v_num1 > v_num2 THEN
      v_temp := v_num1;
      v_num1 := v_num2;
      v_num2 := v_temp;
   END IF;
```

Provide more information based on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways

#### First

```
if your_condition then
   select * from your_table;
```

#### Second

Write your query and add `your_condition` to where clause of query

```
select * from your_table where your_condition;
```